# Jooq order by for known number of arguments

Tags: java, jooq

I use Jooq in my Java application. 
I get from REST endpoint a list of columns (could be zero ,1 2 basically)
to filter my database by using like with an or between them. 
Say for example an incoming request contains number of fields and values f1,f2,f3 to to search by. each field corresponds to column in my entity. 
Basically the sql should be for example :

```
SELECT * from e WHERE location=some_location AND (f1=v1 OR f2=v2 o f3=v3)
```

where f1,v1,f2,v2,f3,v3 are given from REST reuest. It may contains any number of search criteria (zeor, f1,v1 or f1,v1 and f1,v1,f2,v2 or all)
How can I write general JOOQ clause to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to realise that every jOOQ query is a [dynamic SQL query](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), so generating your predicate dynamically based on some input map is simple. Assuming you have the following data structure representing your fields and values:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = ...;
```

You can then translate that to a predicate like so:

```
Condition result =
parameters
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .reduce(
        DSL.noCondition(),
        (condition, entry) -> condition.or(
            // Use Table.field() to find columns by name in your generated table
            // This will NPE if your field was not found. Might want to handle that...
            ((Field<Object>) E.field(entry.getKey())).eq(entry.getValue())
        ),
        Condition::or
    );
```